# Задание вида ссылки

Tags: .htaccess

Доброго времени суток! Подскажите, как сделать ссылку вида `demo.mysite.ru` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Отличный мануал с примерами [htaccess.net.ru](http://htaccess.net.ru/)

через htaccess можно, к примеру, так:

Как разместить несколько сайтов на одном виртуальном хостинге?

Чтобы разместить два или более сайтов на одном виртуальном хостинге, вопреки отведенному вам тарифным планом количеству доменов необходимо в файле ".htaccess" прописать следующие строки:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^newdirectory/ - [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (www.)?newdomain.ru [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) newdirectory/$1 [L]
```

Где:

newdirectory/ - папка, в которой будет лежать второй сайт

[newdomain.ru](http://newdomain.ru) - домен, для которого мы делаем перенаправление

Обратите внимание, что при этом у Вас будет единый почтовый аккаунт. Т.е. если, у Вас существует ящик admin@domain.ru, то после подключения домена [newdomain.ru](http://newdomain.ru) у ящика admin@domain.ru появляется второе имя - admin@newdomain.ru. А при создании любого нового ящика (например info), ему автоматически присваиваются два имени - info@domain.ru и info@newdomain.ru.